# Instant alpha or magic wand tool for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-image

Does anybody know ready-made solutions how to accept instant alpha or magic wand tool for images? Maybe samples or any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "seed fill" algorithms.  Make a mask from that, and then do what you will with it.